# How do I avoid repeating the same word several times?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage, redundancy

I have written the following sentence, but I feel that it's too long, especially the number of the word **"animal"** is too many. 
What's your idea about this? If so, please suggest me how to make it more academic and more concise.

> It is worth mentioning that, I have never ignored participating in extra-curricular activities. In my point of view, **animals** 
>   are our friends and deserve our compassion; Therefore, I joined an **animal** protection agency as an **animal** supporter 
>   activist to help build an **animal**-friendly environment by donating money to the charity and feeding unsheltered **animals**.

Comment: One way: "I participate in extra-curricular activities. In my view, animals are our friends and deserve our compassion, so I joined an animal protection agency as a supporter activist, donating my time and money to the charity." And all the facts are in.

Answer (score 2):

I have always participated in extra-curricular activities. As a supporter activist, I believe **animals** have the right to a friendlier and more compassionate environment, which is why I joined a protection agency that helps look after abandoned **animals**.

Comment: The second animals could become creatures.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think "animals" is still preferable, it's more natural.

Comment: What is more natural than a creature?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey in the sense we talk about "animal rights" and "pet-friendly hotels" the word creatures is not commonly used in these instances. I toyed with the idea of "pets" but then opted for the simpler version. See [this article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/animals/rights/rights_1.shtml) and the number of times the word "animals" is mentioned.

Comment: What might be stilted in conversation might not be so in a statement about oneself, e.g. in an application for college or a resume.

Comment: My comment thanking @MichaelHarvey for his earlier suggestion, removing "animal" from  "protection agency" has been deleted, and not by me :( Miaow!